# Slow Find on Mongo DB

Tags: spring, mongodb

Hi guys i have a problem with mongo, 
i have install mongodb following documentation and, i use mongo with spring.
I have insert on mongo 400000 row of a little of file:

```
List<LinkedHashmap<String,Object> listelem = contains all row of a file.
MongoTemplate mongo =  new MongoTemplate(new MongoClient(), "mydb");
mongo.insert(list, "mycollection");
for(int i=0; i< list.size();i++){
    mongo.insert(list.get(i), "mycollection");
}
```

I have use this solution because if i use:

```
mongo.insert(list, "mycollection");
```

and the content of file is >16MB is very slow to insert. (there is a solution?)

If the i want find all row of a file i make this:

```
MongoTemplate mongo = null;
try {
    mongo = new MongoTemplate(new MongoClient(), "mydb");
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Query search = new Query(Criteria.where("idfile").is(idfile));
List<BasicDBObject> listElem = mongo.find(search,BasicDBObject.class,"mycollection");
```

But this find is very slow and i have insert index on db:

```
db.mycollection.ensureIndex( { "idfile": 1 } )
```

Where am I doing wrong? Thanks.

The time to take a file with 100.000 row on collection that contains 400.000 record is 150 second. And the time to insert this file (23MB) for single row is 240 second, and if i use the single insert the time is 10 minutes.

Comment: Could you post the time your querys take? From what I understand you have a collection where multiple files, each corresponds to around 400.000 entries. This sounds quite large, so you can maybe expect query times in the seconds range. I didn't use Springs mongodb integration yet, so I can't say why it is faster to insert each single list item instead of the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/), you need to put it into practice...

> A convention for storing large files in a MongoDB database. All of the official MongoDB drivers support this convention, as does the mongofiles program.

Comment: I need to insert the row not the entire file.

Comment: **And the time to insert this file (23MB) for single row is 240 second, and if i use the single insert the time is 10 minutes.** therefore you have files < 16MB, [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) is the solution that gives mongodb for large rows...

Comment: thank you, I think I could do in this way. It means that I will use gridfs